# Android - touch two buttons at same time

Tags: android, button, multi-touch

What is the best way to touch two buttons at the same time? I am working on an app that has buttons, like a D-pad and a jump button, to move your character around. Right now I am just using normal buttons and handling them with an OnClickListener. I am having problems when I am running and need to jump at the same time, or if I am running to the right, then want to go left without having to pick my finger up. I know this is possible because it works greats on game like Sonic CD and some others. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OnClick fires only on release. Instead use the touch event handlers so that when they touch occurs, you get the events. However, note that not all devices have multitouch, and thus not all of them will be able to handle the double-touch case correctly. They will provide touch events, but not two of them. Also note that you may receive multiple "pointers" within a touch event, and will have to decide which is "yours" for each button if that matters.

Comment: Also side note: in some version of android, onClick is delayed because of the release processing, so you probably want to avoid that anyhow.

Comment: Thanks Sajid, I'll check into that. If I use the touch events now, would it be better to leave out the buttons and maybe just create bitmaps that were just like the buttons? Then just check if my touch event was on a "button" and handle my presses that way? Right now, my buttons are just laid out on top of a canvas.

Comment: I meant that you could still use the buttons, but I believe all items that have a touch cursor on them do receive touch events. If I am wrong on that, their container would definitely receive both touch points either way. You can in the latter case capture the points and check if they're within the bounds of the buttons.