# Android button onclick multitouch

Tags: android, onclick, multi-touch

I have 2 buttons and I need to read onClick event from second button when first is pressed down **now** and v.v. Like in keyboards. How to do that?

- Edit

No, no! I don't need to check **was** first button clicked or not. I need to listen another onClick events when first or second button is in ACTION_DOWN state couse if I press first button, I can't press second, but I have multitouch.

Comment: Are those Toggle buttons?

Comment: similar to keyboard shortcuts as ctrl+C?

Comment: Whats the purpose? Your question does not seem complete.

Comment: See this discussion http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8959360/android-touch-two-buttons-at-same-time

Comment: No, it's not a toggle button. I want to listen onClick events from two (or three) buttons at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

May be You could try the following code :

Declare a boolean variable in class.

```
private boolean button1IsPressed = false;
```

Write following code for button 1 :

```
button1.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
     @Override
     public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
           button1IsPressed=true;
        } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
           button1IsPressed=false;
        }
     }
  };
```

For Button 2 You can do the following:

```
button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(button1IsPressed){
                  //Write your to do code here
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: if you want to recognize two touches than probably you have to implement ontouchlistener for layout and check for the co ordinates from motionEvent object whether they are within the button boundaries and if so handle the event..

Answer (score 0):

You could try with `onTouchListeners`. In the first button modify a boolean on the down and up event, in the second button, only perform an action when the boolean is true.

Answer (score 0):

If the buttons are toggle buttons, what I think is the case then:

```
public void onToggleClicked(View view) {
    // Is the toggle on?
    boolean on = ((ToggleButton) view).isChecked();

    if (on) {
        // Do something
    } else {
        // Disable vibrate
    }
}
```

The main thing here is the isChecked() function, which may be used when checking which one is checked, so to execute something then. You can set in the XML of the two buttons the following:

`android:onClick="onToggleClicked"` then with isChecked determine which one is checked like this:

```
 boolean on1 = ((ToggleButton) view1).isChecked();
 boolean on2 = ((ToggleButton) view2).isChecked();

if (on1)
  //do something with button2
if (on2)
  //do something with button1
```

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

There's a sample code in android-16/ApiDemos project called "Views -> Splitting Touches across Views" (SplitTouchView.java). In that sample enclosing `LinearLayout` has an attribute `android:splitMotionEvents="true"` which allows to scroll two list views simultaneously.

According to [Android 3.0 API Overview](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-3.0.html) this attribute appeared in this api version:

> Previously, only a single view could accept touch events at one time. Android 3.0 adds support for splitting touch events across views and even windows, so different views can accept simultaneous touch events.